# Add some line before and after a particular line

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, latex

I have many line like

```
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm]{W_muonPtCosTheta_Corr.pdf}
```

in my text file. And I need to find each lines containing this and add a line before and after this. So the final output should be like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] 
{\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm]{W_muon_pt.pdf}};
\draw (2, 3) node {\color{red} $W_{P_T}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You could achieve the same result by redefining the `\includegraphics` macro within LaTeX.

Comment: Please tell me how can I redefine \includegraphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A purely LaTeX solution.

Add the following definitions to the preamble of the LaTeX file

```
  \let\savedincludegraphics\includegraphics
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {
     \savedincludegraphics[#1]{#2}};
     \draw (2, 3) node {\color{red} $W_{P_T}$};
     \end{tikzpicture}}
```

This replaces each occurrence of the macro `includegraphics` with the redefined expansion. You could add additional parameters to the macro to further customize the output.

To introduce a variable caption you will need to change the signature of `\includegraphics`. As it was pointed in the comments it is a good idea to create a new command instead.

```
  \newcommand{\includegraphicscaption}[3][]{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {
     \savedincludegraphics[#1]{#2}};
     \draw (2, 3) node {\color{red} #3};
     \end{tikzpicture}}
```

This command can be used as
    \includegraphicscaption[width=12cm,height=9cm]{W_muon_pt.pdf}{$W_{P_T}$}

**Edit:** there was a typo in the original solution.

Comment: A much better idea is to make a new command with a different name, say `\includegraphics*` or `\tikz_includegraphics` or whatever. You can then do a simple search and replace on this. Don't change standard commands to have a different meaning!

Comment: Getting Error saying : ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

Also, 1 thing I like to mention that Every time the comment $W_{P_T}$ is not same.

Comment: @ramkrishna that's correct, the semicolon was missing.

Comment: @ramkrishna variable comment could be added as an additional parameter. Also following the suggestion by Kaz above it would be safer to give the command a new name.

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu sed you can do:

```
gsed -i 's/\\includegraphics\[width=12cm,height=9cm\]{[^.]*\.pdf}/\\begin{tikzpicture}\n\\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0]\n{&};\n\\draw (2, 3) node {\\color{red} $W_{P_T}$};\n\\end{tikzpicture}\n/' file
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell earlier. But the name of pdf file is different for different lines. How how could I use this command.

Comment: Thanks @zx81, somehow this question turned from sed/awk question to `latex` question :-)